# Reproducir video en streaming en Vue/ HTML

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Tengo una cámara de seguridad IP que transmite el contenido por rstp. Al reproducirla con VLC no tengo ningún problema, pero cuando intento insertar el stream en mi vista de vue, en el navegador me aparece lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que uso:

```
  <embed
    type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
    version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"
    width="200"
    height="200"
    target="rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.2:8554/profile0"
  />
```

¿Cómo podría mostrar el video en mi web? Aun que no sea con VLC me serviría.

Comment: Podrías usar socket.io, nodejs y RTC. Conectas la cámara al pc y transmites lo que se está viendo en la cámara :)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Podrías utilizar `rtsp-relay` ([Documentación](https://github.com/k-yle/rtsp-relay))

Viene un ejemplo para utilizarlo con Vue (Ejemplo copiado de la documentación)

```
<template>
  <canvas ref="canvas" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import { loadPlayer } from 'rtsp-relay/browser';

const canvas = ref(null);

onMounted(() => {
  loadPlayer({
    url: 'ws://localhost:2000/api/stream/2',
    canvas: canvas.value,
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Vue no me reconoce el 'ref', quitándolo no me ha funcionado.

Comment: Para acceder a los `ref` puedes intentar desde el evento `mounted`
`mounted: function() {
    console.log(this.$refs.icanvas);
}`. Si te sirve avísame para editar la respuesta

Comment: No sirve @HeytalePazguato